# Why is npm getting the wrong tag from GitLab

Tags: git, npm, gitlab, npm-install

I have a GitLab repo that I reference in multiple NodeJS projects. I'm using tags for this.

In my package.json for the shared library:

```
{
    "name": "my-shared",
    "version": "4.1.2",
...
}
```

When I make changes, I push this up to the GitLab repo and I can see it up there as expected.
Then `git tag "4.1.2"` and `git push origin "4.1.2"`

In the referencing project's package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        ...
        "my-shared": "git+https://gitlab+deploy-token-25649:my-token@gitlab.com/url/my-shared.git#4.1.2",
        ...
}
```

And then, obviously `npm i` inside that project.

This has been working well for years, but it's suddenly stopped working. Now, when I run the `npm i` command inside the referencing project(s), I get version 4.0.32 instead of version 4.1.2 - when I drill into /node_modules/my-shared/package.json, it's v4.0.32, and the rest of the code supports this.

This happens on all my (10+) referencing projects.
I've deleted the node_modules folder and package-lock.json files before running the npm installation and the same thing happens.

All tags for the my-shared project are displaying as expected in GitLab.

I have no idea what I might have done to screw this up or how to resolve it. Any help, please?

Comment: You ever figure this out? Experiencing the same thing when trying to pull a tag from one of my private repos.

Comment: I've updated to npm 6.14.11 and the issue seems to have gone away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to have gone away after updating npm to v6.14.11

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and found that in my pipeline yaml file, I was instructing Bitbucket to use a cache for my node build. Perhaps you have something similar in your Gitlab pipeline. After I removed the cache from my pipeline file, the correct tag was then installed.